# How to Append a Text File in an Azure Blob with a Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I've got a text file I need to append data to daily with a timer Azure Function.  The text file is a comma separated file.
I've created my CloudBlobClient and knew how to make my Shared Access Policy and Token.
I just don't know how to use this to upload.  I only know how to get an access URI from the tutorial I'm working with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've got a text file I need to append data to daily with a timer Azure Function.

You can try to use append blob that is optimized for append operations. According to your description, you know how to get [SAS URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1), so you can use SAS URI to create a reference to an append blob, and append a file to an append blob, the following code is for your reference.

```
CloudAppendBlob appendBlob = new CloudAppendBlob(new Uri("https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{your_container}/append-blob.log?st=2017-09-25T02%3A10%3A00Z&se=2017-09-27T02%3A10%3A00Z&sp=rwl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=d0MENO44GjtBLf7L8U%2B%2F2nGwPAayjiVSSHaKJgEkmIs%3D"));


appendBlob.AppendFromFile("{filepath}\source.txt");
```

Comment: Be advised BlockBlobs cannot be accessed as AppendBlobs. The file needs to be created as an AppendBlob for this to work. Your use case does call for an AppendBlob, so I would advise to create the blob as an AppendBlob :)

Comment: Yes, the file needs to be created as an append blob.

Comment: Append blob. Append blob. Append blob.

Comment: Should this code run? Struggling for hours with it. The AccountKey seems to be missing. And there is a lot of 'garbage' after the file name. Can I remove that?