# Is there any way to copy incremental data from SQL Server to Blob Storage Through Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-server

I am trying to copy incremental data from Azure SQL to Blob Storage but it overwrite all the existing data in every file. Can you provide me any work around for this problem

Comment: Hello, and welcome. What code are you using to copy this data? Can you include it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline will need to only capture **'delta' data** rather than all data.
It will require a number of lookup activities, copy activity which only copies delta data and a stored proc activity for updating the last modified date (to be used for future copying)

Check out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-powershell

Comment: Thanks, But it will create a seperate blob file for every delta load in container...I need only one .txt file which contain its's existing as well as delta data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create new file in each delta load and after that append delta file data to original file. For append file data you use this link [How to Append a Text File in an Azure Blob with a Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416808/how-to-append-a-text-file-in-an-azure-blob-with-a-azure-function).